express js session not being maintained
I separated the front end back end and implemented it, but even if I run an api like the bottom, it is only saved in the session at the beginning and there is nothing in the session if I call it up right away. Why is that?
//front project
//api.js
const BASE_URL ='http://localhost:3000';


export async function loginUser(useremail,password){
const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/login`,{
method:'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
},  
credentials: 'include',
body: JSON.stringify({useremail, password}),
});

    const result= await response.json();
    console.log(result);
    return result;

}


export async function fetchPosts(){
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/posts`,{
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
        },
        credentials: 'include',     
    });
    return response.json();
}

//back project
//index.js
const express=require('express');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes');
const colors = require('colors');
const moment = require('moment');
const path = require('path');
const cors =require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
require('dotenv').config();





const app= express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use(session({
    secret:'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 24 * 6 * 60 * 10000,
      sameSite: 'None',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
  }
}));
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true,
  }),
)


app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));

app.use('/',userRoutes); 


const PORT=3000;

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack); 
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        message: err.message || 'Internal Server Error'
    });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request URL: ${req.url}, Method: ${req.method}`);
    next();
});

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`.green);
});

//userRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController= require('../controllers/userController');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});

router.post('/login', userController.login);
router.post('/posts', userController.getAllPosts);

//userController.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const usersFilePath = path.join(__dirname,'../data/users.json');


userController={
login: async (req,res)=>{
                const {useremail,password}=req.body;
                const userData={useremail,password};
                console.log("userData",userData);



             fs.readFile(usersFilePath,'utf-8',(err,data)=>{
                if(err){
                     console.error('error: ',err);
                     return res.status(500).json({message: 'error'});
                }

                const users= JSON.parse(data)|| [];

                
                const user = users.find(u => u.useremail === useremail && u.password === password);
                
                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(401).json({ success: false});
                }

                const sessionUser={
                    userId: user.userId,
                    useremail: user.useremail,
                    nickname: user.nickname,
                    profile: user.profile
           
                }
                req.session.user=sessionUser;
                console.log("req.session.user::::",req.session.user)
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'success', user: user });
            });
        },
        getAllPosts: async (req,res)=>{
            const user = req.session;
           console.log("user session :",req.session);
            
        }
    };
}


module.exports=userController;

If you run on the same project without separating it, the session works well, but since you separated the project, the session doesn't seem to work.
